# Bayes' Theorem, Rigorously

Tags: probability-theory

For a given probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ Bayes' rule is given by
$$
P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)} \quad \text{for all } A,B \in \mathcal{F}.
$$

However, in many examples (in fact, all of them that I've found) there is hardly a mention of a probability space, much less a sigma algebra.  I'm hoping to get a little clarification based on the following simple example.

Consider the example problem at the bottom of the page [here](http://stattrek.com/probability/bayes-theorem.aspx), where they state $\Omega = \{\text{rain}, \text{no rain}\} := \{A_1, A_2\}$.  They then define the event $B := \text{weatherman predicts rain}$.  I guess the sigma algebra is $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega) = \{\emptyset, A_1, A_2, \Omega\}$, but I'm already confused as to where $B$ would fit in here - since they define it as an event (and they plug it into probability measures), it must but be that $B_1 \in \mathcal{F}$.  Maybe $B$ is really a random variable, whose preimage is in $\mathcal{F}$?  I don't think this works, either, though.

What would a rigorous setup of this simple problem look like?

Comment: Consider $\{\text{rain}, \text{ no rain}\} \times \{\text{rain predicted}, \text{ no rain predicted}\}$

Comment: The authors who wrote the problem botched their sample space.  My advice to you is to study fundamental probabilistic concepts from a more robust source like a good undergraduate book in probability, rather than stat trek dot com.  The correct sample space to facilitate the analysis of prior/posterior probability is the product space with pairs of outcomes (rain, predict rain), (not rain, predict rain), (rain, predict no rain), (no rain, predict no rain).

Comment: @guest Believe me, I'm not studying from that website, it just happened to be the top site when I Googled for an example. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Your statement of Baye's rule is not really correct.  We also need to assume that both $A$ and $B$ are events with positive probability.  The sample space by Henry above is suitable for representing your desired $A$ and $B$ as events (elements of the sigma-algebra), one would also need to assume $Pr[A]>0$ and $Pr[B]>0$ (to avoid division by zero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as "rigor" goes, Bayes rule as stated is nothing but a restatement of the definition of conditional probability, which is usually taken as being somewhat axiomatic in probability.  That is, whenever $P(B) > 0$ we *define* the conditional probability of $A$ given $B$ as,

$$
\begin{align}
P(A | B) &= \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} .
\end{align}
$$

But then obviously (assuming also that $P(A) > 0$),

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{P(B | A) P(A)}{P(B)} &= \frac{P(A \cap B) / P(A) \times P(A)}{P(B)} \\
&= \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} \\
&= P(A | B) .
\end{align}
$$

So in essence, Bayes rule is more or less assumed to be true rather than being demonstrated rigorously.

Regarding the example, if $\Omega$ contains only the two elements $\{ \text{rain} \}$ and $\{ \text{not rain} \}$, then who is the weatherman?  He doesn't even exist yet.

Comment: Finally... somebody who can make a difference between a definition and a theorem. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the "orthodox" way of solving your problem is this: your probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma ,P)$ is not much important as long as you konw that $A_1,A_2,B \in \Sigma$. What is really important is the sigma-algebra generated by those events you are taking into account.

You can also look at your $A_1,A_2,B$ as the preimage of random variables taking values in $\{ 0,1\}$ so that $A_1 = X^{-1}(\{1\})$ where $X$ is " $1$ if it rains on Marie's wedding, $0$ if not" etc.

Having said I'm not a specialist, this (I guess) is how a kolmogorovian probabilist will answer your question. Still the problem of finding the "preliminary" probabilities (i.e. $P(A_1)$ and $P(A_2)$ of your link) is not solved since we have supposed nothing on $\Omega$. The problem with the exercises in which "there is hardly a mention of a probability space" is that they need a lot of work to be set down in the kolmogorovian approach: for your problem you can think $\Omega$ is the set of days (in an year?in two years?..) so that $A_1$ are the rainy days and $B$ are the days in wich the weatherman predicts rain. This could support (I guess) a frequentist approach in order to determine the "preliminary" probabilities. This supposing we all could agree with the choice of $\Omega$ being one (or two,three,..) years. But there are problems that can't be reduced to frequencies at all! This question led me recently to the subjectivist (or bayesian) approach to the theory of probability, in which the Bayes rule have quite a different role. If you are interested check http://www.princeton.edu/~bayesway/